# Can't write to certain directories. It says "The system cannot find the file specified." Need help troubleshooting

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, file-permissions

Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask, but I don't know where else I should ask. (I previously asked this on StackOverflow, and was told to ask here.)

On my development computer, which is Windows 10, I cannot use the `mkdir` command in `cmd` to create a folder, but only in some locations.

(I found this issue when I discovered that in my python program, `os.mkdir()` was failing. (It used to work in the past.) However, I can   do right click -> new folder as usual in windows explorer.)

```
C:\Users\tchiranantha>cd Documents

C:\Users\tchiranantha\Documents>mkdir asdf
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\Users\tchiranantha\Documents>cd ..

C:\Users\tchiranantha>cd Music

C:\Users\tchiranantha\Music>mkdir zxcv
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\Users\tchiranantha\Music>cd ..

C:\Users\tchiranantha>mkdir qwrwefdwe

C:\Users\tchiranantha>cd qwrwefdwe

C:\Users\tchiranantha\qwrwefdwe>mkdir dfsdfd

C:\Users\tchiranantha\qwrwefdwe>cd dfsdfd

C:\Users\tchiranantha\qwrwefdwe\dfsdfd>
```

Can someone help me figure out what could possibly have happened here, and how could I fix this? (Hopefully my computer isn't broken. I don't  want to reinstall Windows or replace my development computer.)

I tried googling, and the answers seemed to only apply when one attempts to created multiple nested directories in one go, which is not what I'm doing here.

---

EDIT: I've found that I am also unable to write to any files in certain folders. What is wrong with my computer???

```
C:\Users\tchiranantha>echo foo > something.txt

C:\Users\tchiranantha>type something.txt
foo

C:\Users\tchiranantha>cd Documents

C:\Users\tchiranantha\Documents>echo foo > something.txt
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: @Ramhound As in the console log I pasted, something like 31 characters. Not long.

Comment: @Ramhound As shown in my question, I tried to create the directory `asdf` in `C:\Users\tchiranantha\Documents`

Comment: run in cmd: **`where md & where mkdir`** and **`doskey /macros`**

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe `doskey /macros` outputs nothing.

Comment: @TheemathasChirananthavat - “What is wrong with my computer?” - Nothing is wrong with your computer.  Your IT department has not given you the necessary permissions

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the security department in my company stopping it.